# Sequential import of datafiles according to rule in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, import

I have a list of .txt datafiles to import. Suppose they are called like that

file100data.txt file101data.txt ... file109data.txt I want to import them all using `readtable`.

I tried using the for to specify a vector a = [0:9] through which matlab could loop the readtable command but I cannot make it work.

```
for a = [0:9]
   T_a_ = readtable('file10_a_data.txt')   
end
```

I know I cannot just put `_a_` where I want the vector to loop through, so my question is how can I actually do it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that should work even if you have missing files in your folder (*e.g.* you have file100data.txt to file107data.txt, but you are missing file file108data.txt and file109data.txt):

```
files=dir('file10*data.txt'); %list all data files in your folder
nof=size(files,1); %number of files
for i=1:nof %loop over the number of files
table_index=files(i).name(7) %recover table index from data filename
eval(sprintf('T%s = readtable(files(i).name)', table_index)); %read table
end
```

Now, please note that is it generally regarded as poor practice to dynamically name variables in Matlab (see [this post](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/105936-how-to-make-dynamic-variable-names-a1-a2-an-with-for-loop-using-eval-num2str) for example). You may want to resort to structures or cells to store your data.

Comment: I was avoiding trying to use `eval` in my answer because as you quite rightly point out, it's really bad practice.

Comment: Thank you! May I ask you what the 7 in the fourth line means? EDIT: nevermind I got it -it is the 7th place of the name! Thank you again!

Comment: `files(i).name(7)` returns the 7th character in your filename. For instance, in file103data.txt, it corresponds to the "3" at the end of "103".

Comment: @Maria: please don't use this, it's really not good practice to use `eval`.

Comment: @Maria: I have to agree with am304: my solution is a quick fix for your problem, but in the long term, you are better off using structures.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the value of `a` into a string and combine strings together, like this:

```
   Tables = struct(); 
   for a = 0:9
       % note: using dynamic structure field names to store the imported tables
       fname = ['file10_' num2str(a) '_data'];
       Tables.(fname) = readtable([fname '.txt']);   
   end
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without structure fields?

Comment: I don't think so. It's probably the most elegant way. You don't want to use `eval` ...

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it with eval even though it is less elegant? I am under time pressure and don't have the time dive into structure fields so I need a quick solution that is probably less elegant.. that would be really nice :)

Comment: Sorry, `eval` is really bad, you shouldn't us it, see why at (for example) https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/. Your time constraints are not really my concern, I gave a perfectly good solution that should work just fine. If you don't want to use it or learn the necessary constructs, it's your problem, but it's really not that hard, see [Generate Field Names from Variables](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html).